# Globally update pattern styles

Tags: block-editor

Currently if we create a pattern in one page, and modify the styles, for example add some spacing, update margins and etc, they are not updated in other pages.

I use a pattern called callMe which shows a CTA at the bottom of some pages, if I update it on the homepage, I want this pattern to be updated on all other pages.

Is it general understanding that **patterns should be updated manually across all pages** if it is updated in one page?

Is this possible with Patterns or I should create a "Template Part"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it general understanding that patterns should be updated manually
> across all pages if it is updated in one page?

Yes.

**Block Patterns** are essentially shortcuts for adding a collection of blocks all at once. Once the blocks are inserted they exist as independent blocks just like any others. There's no meaningful difference in the result of adding a block pattern and adding that same collection of blocks manually.

**Reusable Blocks** are a bit closer to what you describe, as any changes you make to them will be made everywhere the reusable block is used. These can be created by selecting a block, or blocks, and clicking *Create Reusable block* in Block options menu. The trouble is that *any* changes that you make will be applied everywhere the block is used, not just styling changes.

**Template Parts** are very similar to Reusable Blocks, except that they are intended for site structure and only available in the Site Editor.

There's a good support article describing the differences [here](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/comparing-patterns-template-parts-and-reusable-blocks/).

If you want to make styling changes for a block or group of blocks across all your existing content without making content changes to those blocks then unfortunately I don't think that's currently supported. The closest thing would probably be using [Global Styles](https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/global-styles/) to support changing styles globally. If global styles are added that affect the blocks in your block pattern then the styling of all existing instances of those blocks would be updated whenever the global styles are updated.

Comment: Thank you, I think making it `Reusable Block` is the best option here

Comment: also do you know if we can create usable blocks in the theme code? for example patterns can be added in the patterns folder, what about reusable blocks? I see there is an option to `Import from JSON` but what about the theme?

Comment: I don't think you can. Reusable blocks are essentially content, so they're created by the user. You could create some on theme activation with `wp_insert_post()` (I don't have the post type on hand) but that's not something themes would be expected to do.